# Change /etc/, /var/ permissions to 777

Tags: permissions, centos, root

Well, I was being lazy to properly setup the properties of the files and now I set up the permissions recursively the folders /etc/ and /var/ to 777. Now I can't ssh into the machine but worse I can't even login as root into the machine anymore to change the permissions back.

Is there any fix or is it just easier to reisntall the OS?

I am using CentOS6.4

Thank you.

Comment: What error do you receive when you attempt to login as the root user?  Seems strange that global `rwe` flag would prevent you from logging in.

Comment: what are you having trouble with specifically? with 777 everybody should be able to access everything. ALso, you say that you can no longer SSH to the box. If, for some reason, this messed up ssh, you're going to need to sit down at the computer. tut [here](http://www.centos.org/docs/4/html/rhel-sbs-en-4/s1-q-and-a-root-passwd.html) on recovering root password. From there you can set the permissions to whatever you would like. Also [here](http://askubuntu.com/a/309031) on Askubuntu someone seems to have had a similar problem. Adapt their commands to your situation.

Comment: This answer also helps with fixing permissions back to normal. http://askubuntu.com/a/115362

Comment: Remember to always include the error messages you get.

Comment: I usually link http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12998/wrongly-set-chmod-777-problems to questions like these. The link handles the more severe case of recursively 777ing `/`, and argues that it might very well be less work to reinstall, depending on how your system setup looks. It is very well worth thinking about, in my eyes.

Answer (score 3):

You won't need to reinstall.  One option is to boot off an installer image and then mount the storage device (make sure to do it as read-write), go in and manually fix the mounted copy, then boot back into your installed OS.

Answer (score 1):

The "problem" is that SSH is ignoring your private keys because they are world readable.  You can simply log into the server over a console and change the permissions on the file.

Have a look at section 3.14 of [this](http://www.openssh.org/faq.html) document for what to change.  (You can fix the permissions on your private keys or disable StrictModes in your config)

Comment: From the original question, I don't believe that console access will work either.

Comment: It should, except he can't log in as root.  This generally means logging in as the user who set up the computer and issuing the command "sudo su" or "sudo /bin/bash" to get root access.

Comment: I was operating under the belief that root wouldn't login from console due to /etc/passwd being 777, rather than it being disabled.  I'm not familiar with CentOS specifically anymore.

Comment: I would be extraordinarily surprised if the permissions on /etc/password were checked, and only marginally less if /etc/shadow were checked.  The "login as root" limitation is much more likely to be with /etc/securetty not allowing root logins from the console.